# How to keep a state of a tab in a chrome extention

Tags: javascript, tabs, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a chrome extension that needs to keep a state of each tabs in which the script will be executed.
My first idea was to have a map in the background page that associate the current tab id to the state of the tab.

I've just seen that the `chome.tabs.getCurrent` method cannot be used to get the tab id of page that execute the content script.
I've seen that the `chrome.tabs.getSelected` method is often recommended but I can't use this method because my script can be called in background (for example, when a page is reloaded automaticly) and then the tab can be not selected.

So I whould know how to get the id of the current tab or how to keep a state of a tab.

Comment: What do you mean by tab state, its url? You need to describe in more details when exactly are you planning to run this script and what it is you are trying to save.

Comment: I want to make an extension like IMacro. The goal is to automate the execution of a scenario. In some case, I need to maintain a counter and this counter needs to be independent between pages.

Comment: So you just need a tab id? Which tab is it for, current one or all tabs in window? When do you need it, at any time or when user clicks something somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I only need tab id. I need it for all tabs in any window. I need this information when the content of the tab changes (when a new page is loaded). I don't say when the user clicks somewhere because the page can be changed by the extension (and so I can't use the chrome.tabs.getSelected method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, I only need to access to `sender.tab.id`

Script in the backgroung page :

```
var states = new Object();
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.method == "setState") {
      states[sender.tab.id] = request.state;
      sendResponse({});
    } else if(request.method == "getState") {
      var state = states[sender.tab.id];
      sendResponse(state);
    } else {
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
    }
  });
```

And the code I need in the content script :

```
function saveState(state) {
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "setState", state: state}, function() {});
}

function restoreState() {
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({method: "getState"}, doTheJob);
}

function doTheJob(state) {
  // do the job
  console.log(state);

  var newState;
  if(state==undefined || state==null) {
    newState = { count: 1 };
  } else {
    newState = state;
    newState.count++;
  }
  saveState(newState);
}

restoreState();
```